# Difference between 僕等 and 僕ら?

Tags: usage, nuances

It’s in an amazarashi song. When he sings, he says 僕ら but if when I look at the lyrics it says 僕等. Is there a difference in these?

Comment: Related? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11746/usage-of-kanji-for-words-usually-written-in-kana

Answer (score 1):

ら is one of the kun-readings of 等, so there is no difference. The kanji 等 has several readings.

- ら: (attaches to person pronouns and person names) -s, and colleagues/friends, *et al*

  > 彼等【かれら】, 君等【きみら】, 私等【わたしら】, 研究者等【けんきゅうしゃら】, 田中等【たなから】
- など, とう: (attaches to other types of noun) and so on, and similar, *et cetra*

  > 自動車等【じどうしゃとう】, 研究等【けんきゅうとう】

  See: [Inaccurate ruby for 等?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32263/5010)

This is admittedly confusing, and this is why -ら is usually written in hiragana (彼ら, 田中ら, ...). Still, you may occasionally encounter -ら in kanji.