# Different pronunciations of 等

Tags: pronunciation

When 等 comes after a word, how can I know when to pronounce it as など or とう?

According to a colleague of mine, it's usually pronounced とう when read and など when spoken.

Comment: Related: [Inaccurate ruby for 等?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32263/5010)

Comment: ら is another possible suffix written as 等 and can be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

など reading is [kun'yomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji#Kun%27yomi_(native_reading)) (native Japanese in most cases, but there are few exceptions).

とう reading is [on'yomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanji#On%27yomi_(Sino-Japanese_reading)) (Sino-Japanese; borrowed from Middle Chinese to Old Japanese or Middle Japanese).

When both kun'yomi and on'yomi readings are possible, on'yomi sounds more formal / literary. (Compare how in English, words borrowed from Latin or French often sound more formal / literary.)